# In my database I have time stored in minutes. The user edits it in 24hr format on a form. How should I code it? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an integer field in a database that represents minutes from midnight for a single day. On the form that displays the time value, I want to show a value between 00:00 and 23:59. I'm using a text_field.

When the form is submitted, I want the following events to occur in this order.
1) Validate the form string using a regular expression to make sure it is between 00.00 and 23.59.
2) If validation passes, modify the string to minutes from midnight.
3) Save the information to database.

Here's how I implemented it.My model is called availabilities. and the field is called start_tod, (start time of day)

```
class Availability < ActiveRecord::Base   
  validates_format_of :start_tod, with: /\A([01][0-9]|2[0-3])(:|\.)([0-5][0-9])\Z/ 
end
```

and in the availabilities controller I have. str_to_tod() simply converts the time string to an integer.

```
def update
  params[:availability][:start_tod] = str_to_tod(params[:availability][:start_tod])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @availability.update(availability_params)
      format.html { redirect_to session[:previous_url], notice: 'Availability was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @availability }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @availability.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Similar process is applied to the create method. If I try to enter a start time of day on the form of 09:30, validation fails. I've printed the value out and discovered when I validate it, it has already been converted to 540 from 09:30. How do I make the validation operate on the 09:30 string. If there's a better way of doing this please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I'm going to answer my question. I think there is a better solution. Use a java time picker or HTML5 time or a regular expression. It's a much neater solution. Here's how I did it...

On the form I have

```
<%= f.text_field :start_tod, value: tod_to_str(@availability.start_tod), pattern: '([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[:|\.][0-5][0-9]|24[:|\.]00', title: '00:00 to 24:00' %>
```

where `@availability.start_tod` is the time in minutes from midnight and `tod_to_str()` is the function that converts minutes to a string like 14:00. the pattern ensures that only a valid time string will ever make it's way back to the server.

In the model I have

```
before_validation :type_cast_times

def str_to_tod(tod_str)
  return tod_str[0].to_i * 600 +
         tod_str[1].to_i * 60 +
         tod_str[3].to_i * 10 +
         tod_str[4].to_i * 1
end

def type_cast_times
  self.start_tod = str_to_tod(self.start_tod_before_type_cast)
end
```

You have to call `type_cast_times()` before validation, so if any server validation fails, the correct time value in minutes is passed back to the form when it displays the error

Answer (score 0):

you will need "before_type_cast"

So you have to write your own validation method like this:

```
validate(:format_to_time)

def format_to_time
  return /\A([01][0-9]|2[0-3])[:.]([0-5][0-9])\Z/.match(self.start_tod_before_type_cast)
end
```

Comment: I tried that but get the error "can't convert Fixnum to String". It seems to be taking the database value, converting it to a string and then validating. The validation I want is on the string before it is converted to a fixnum. Actually the purpose of the validation is to make sure I can convert it to a fixnum

Comment: oh... I just saw that you do `params[:availability][:start_tod] = str_to_tod(params[:availability][:start_tod])` before you even do the validation! I would do the "casting to int" in a before_* method.

Comment: I would also move the str_to_tod to the model

Comment: Getting closer. I tried adding `params[:availability][:start_tod] = str_to_tod(params[:availability][:start_tod])` to `before_save` in the model. Now it says **undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Availability:0x78cf270>**

Comment: Oh, sorry, you misunderstood. You need to move the method "str_to_tod" (right now in the controller) to the model and call it in a before_save. You won't need `params[:availability][:start_tod] = str_to_tod(params[:availability][:start_tod])`at all

Comment: Everything is working except for one small thing. If I type a "start_tod" of 0y:00, validation fails and the form re-opens with the validation error. It lets me know that 0y:00 is not a valid time. The problem is, now the "start_tod" edit box contains 00:00, i.e the result after casting. If a careless user presses the update button again, the update passes with a "start_tod" of 0:00, which is probably not what they want.

Comment: if i were you i would add a `attr_accessor(:start_tod)` and would rename your db field (or vice versa) and would not do it in 1 variable. that way you will still have the user input even after cast